# JavaScript, Node.JS : unable to update a variable in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building an API via Node.js.

I have a loop that add values to an initially empty array, but the array stays empty. The following is my code.

```
get_doc_name = async (event) => {
    const connection = await db.connection()

    try {
        const doc_ids = event.doc_ids

        // array that has JSONs as element
        // e.g. [ {1 : 'certificate.pdf'}, {2: 'report.jpeg'}]
        let dict = []

        await doc_ids.map(async function(id) {
            const sql = "SELECT link FROM document WHERE id=?"
            await connection.query(sql, id, async function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err
                const link = await result[0].link
                const doc_name = await link.split('/').pop()
                await dict.push({
                    key: id,
                    value: doc_name
                })
                console.log(dict)
            })
        })

        return dict

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)

    } finally {
        connection.end()
        console.log('MySQL connection closed')
    }
}
```

The function returns an empty array. However, it prints the updated array when `console.log(dict)` is executed. I need the function to return the updated array.

Moreover, when the function is called, the codes in the 'finally' statement are executed before the codes in 'try' statement. The program prints `MySQL connection closed` before it prints `dict`.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are retrieving data from DB, it is better to use serial Promise instead of parallel Promises to get data from DB. The way I do is in serial Promise.

It is a better practice to get data with `SELECT link FROM document WHERE id in ()` instead of `id=` in your SQL because you don't need to make multiple I/O to the DB in your case.

However, I didn't change this part of logic.

Also, you should promisefy your `connection.query` and return a value from it.
I make it in a `getResult()` function.

```js
get_doc_name = async event => {
  try {
    const connection = await db.connection();
    try {
      const doc_ids = event.doc_ids;

      // array that has JSONs as element
      // e.g. [ {1 : 'certificate.pdf'}, {2: 'report.jpeg'}]
      let dict = [];

      //Promises in serial here
      for (const id of doc_ids) {
        const result = await getResult(connection, id);
        dict.push(result);
      }
      console.log(dict);

      return dict;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
      await connection.end();
      console.log("MySQL connection closed");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

function getResult(connection, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sql = "SELECT link FROM document WHERE id=?";
    connection.query(sql, id, function (err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      const link = result[0].link;
      const doc_name = link.split("/").pop();
      resolve({ key: id, value: doc_name });
    });
  });
}

get_doc_name()
  .then(dict => console.log(dict))
  .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I get an error of ```ReferenceError: connection is not defined``` for ```connection.end()'``` since the connection is defined in the try statement. Can I get an advise for this? I don't think it is a good idea to put it outside the try statement since declaring connection can cause error.

Comment: @ambb, I updated my answer. I use one more trycatch to handle the connection.